# Finding a type of a variable in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a following task from my mentor:

1. Type a value with a prompt and make it a number with unary plus
2. console.log if it's even or odd
3. If it's not a number, add another console log

Here's the code I have right now, and I can't really understand what's wrong:

```
x = prompt("Enter your value: ");

if(x % 2 === 0) {
    console.log("x is an even number");
} else  {
    console.log("x is an odd number")
}

if (typeof x === "!Number"){
    console.log("Whoops, it seems like you're mistaken");
}
```

Comment: Try logging `typeof x` and will find it is always '"string"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several issues in your code:

1. You should check the type of `x` before you judge it's even or odd.
2. The type of `x` can only be `string` since it's come from [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), but you can still know if it's a valid number string by [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function.
3. If you want to know whether a type of a variable is `number` or not, it should be `typeof x !== 'number'`. `typeof x === '!Number'` will never be true(also the case matters).

Here's an example that how you could write the code:

```js
let x = prompt("Enter your value: ");

if (isNaN(x)){
    console.log("Whoops, it seems like you're mistaken");
} else if(x % 2 === 0) {
    console.log("x is an even number");
} else  {
    console.log("x is an odd number")
}
```